# tabbar controller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view based application in which at a later point of time I have to load a tabbar controller. Can any one please tell me how to do this. I tried adding uitabbar but doesnt seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY5hhkEH4vs Youtube tutorials would be a good start !

Comment: I am not looking for a tabbar based application. I have a view based application after flowing 2 levels deeps I need a tabbar view. I dont know how to do this. Will be using tabbar controller or using tabbar.

Comment: It's the same implementation! Create a tab Bar Controller in the for that particular view, and add it to the view :)

Comment: should I just add tabbar controller as sub view??

Comment: I tried this way the problem I am having is half of the tabbars icons  are hidden. I mean the screen spaciing is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The better way is to take one UITabbarController in MainWindow.xib and bind it with your appDelegate's IBOutlet UITabbarController

```
[window addSubView:tabbarController.view];
[window addSubView:viewController.view];
```

Now make function

```
-(void)showTabBarController:(BOOL)bShown{
    tabbarController.view.hidden = !bShown;
    [window bringSubViewToFront:tabbarController.view];
}
```

Now call this function whenever necessary,  For example, if you do not want tabbar at launching, you can hide it on didFinishLaunching by calling [self showTabBarController:FALSE];

and if you want to show tabbarcontroller at any view controller, you can unhide it by calling [appDelegate showTabBarController:TRUE];

Hope it helps

Comment: I have a navigation controller inside view controllor and after two levels deep I have different number of tabs based on the choice made on previous tabs. I am not sure how this will work if I have  a tab bar at the start?

Comment: will it be any situation where from tabbar controller, you can go back to your navigation controller???

Comment: I did an application using tabbar and nav controllor. In that case nav controller will be present inside tabbar view right?If I use tabbar controller as rootview controller than I can move to upper levels where the app started. I am sorry I am little confused.

Comment: upto two levels tabbarcontroller will be hidden, and when you want to show tabbar on third level, you can unhide tabbarcontroller.

Comment: So this wil be a navigation based application having tabbar controllor??

Comment: ok, take view controller and tabbar controller separately in MainWindow.xib, take IBOutlets rootViewController and tabbarController in appdelegate, and add both views into window. and then hide tabbar controller's view. Now, at this point, you will have only navigation controller running...

Comment: @JigneshBrahmkhatri let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/986/discussion-between-din-and-jignesh-brahmkhatri)

Comment: I have added image of MainWindow.xib for better understandings, where Test View Controller is a root view controller, and There is another TabbarController inside which there are 3 navigation controllers, having 3 tabs...

Comment: Thanks. I am checking with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a normal tabbar, and then handling the tabbar call backs by making your view controller its delegate

Comment: Can you tell me how to populate the tabs in the tabbar with views? I added delegate. but I dont know how to add the view to a tabbar. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Make your app delegate the class which will implement the tabbar delegate methods. Once you have done implement this method   `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item; ` in your app delegate, and checking which item was clicked make appropriate changes. If you check the header files for tabbarcontroller, this is what is precise mechanism which tabbarcontroller follows to implement its tab switching. Hope it helps..